# Translate this C function to PHP

Tags: php, c++, code-translation

I am trying to translate the following C code, which basically just tries to convert an arbitrary integer value into a character from a pool of characters, into PHP:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

uint8_t GetCharacter(uint32_t value) {
    static const char* valid_characters = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMOPQRSTUVWabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw";
    static const size_t valid_characters_l = strlen(valid_characters);
    uint8_t c = valid_characters[value % valid_characters_l];
    return valid_characters[(value << c) % valid_characters_l];
}

int main() {
    uint32_t array[] = {176, 52, 608, 855};
    for (size_t i=0; i < 4; i++) {
        uint8_t c = GetCharacter(array[i]);
        std::cout << array[i] << ": " << (uint32_t) c << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Which yields

```
176: 109
52: 114
608: 85
855: 65
```

---

The PHP code I've been able to come up with however yields the following:

```
176: 109
52: 114
608: 85
855: 104   // << Here's the problem
```

I am very sure I translated it exactly and I am unable to find the issue.

```
<?php

function getCharacter($index) {
    $chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMOPQRSTUVWabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw";
    $c = ord(substr($chars, $index % strlen($chars)));
    return ord(substr($chars, ($index << $c) % strlen($chars)));
}

function main() {
    $array = array(176, 52, 608, 855);
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        echo "$value: " . getCharacter($value) . "\n";
    }
}

main();
```

Could someone point me into the right direction to solve this problem?

Comment: Works on my machine - what version of PHP are you using?

Comment: I would print out the values of `strlen($chars)`, `$index`, and `$c`, as a first debugging step. It may be you have a problem with overflow of the shift operation because of number of bits on your machine. In principle `$c` can be > 32...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the problem is that the number `($index << c)` is `3,586,129,920` which is > 2 billion, and cannot be properly represented by a signed 32 bit integer. Since you don't explicitly define the data type of `$value` in php, I think the arithmetic ends up being implementation dependent.

Actually it is surprising that things work at all - you are shifting a 32 bit number by a value greater than 32 which is going to lead to undefined behavior, I think. You might want to re-think the underlying math, and in particular consider the underflow / overflow behavior of your code.

As a potential solution, you might notice that you have a finite number of possible inputs and corresponding outputs - you could actually create a direct lookup table. I believe I did this correctly (using the C++ version of your code with some modifications) - it surprised me a little bit that it didn't result in a 1:1 mapping. The lookup string becomes:

```
$lookupString = "6RQtrpp07TU4AP1IDKmjl8QD7WjitmwUAcjT3AT9MuAu3PUKJtIb5vS"
```

And your php code can be reduced to

```
$value = ord(substr($lookupString, $input % 55));
```

Where `55` is the length of the `lookupString`.

Interesting observation: a number of characters appear more than once; other characters are never used. This means that this is not a very "good" encoding scheme (if that is what it is trying to be).

For reference, this is the code I used to determine the lookup string:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

static const char* valid_characters = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMOPQRSTUVWabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw";

uint8_t GetCharacter(uint32_t value) {
    static const size_t valid_characters_l = strlen(valid_characters);
    uint8_t c = valid_characters[value % valid_characters_l];    
    return valid_characters[(value << c) % valid_characters_l];
}

int main() {
    uint32_t array[] = {176, 52, 608, 855};
    for (size_t i=0; i < 55; i++) {
        uint8_t c = GetCharacter(i + '0');
        std::cout << char(c);
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost certainly encountering the "problem" because you're running on 32-bit PHP, or PHP on Windows (which doesn't support 64-bit integers regardless of the OS bitness). The issue is that you're overflowing the integer on the shift operation:

64-bit PHP:

```
PHP_INT_MAX: 9223372036854775807
C: 66, index: 176, strlen: 55, shift: 704, substr: mnopqrstuvw :: 176: 109
C: 117, index: 52, strlen: 55, shift: 468374361246531584, substr: 9ABCDEFGHIJKLMOPQRSTUVWabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw :: 52: 57
C: 51, index: 608, strlen: 55, shift: 1369094286720630784, substr: hijklmnopqrstuvw :: 608: 104
C: 86, index: 855, strlen: 55, shift: 3586129920, substr: ABCDEFGHIJKLMOPQRSTUVWabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw :: 855: 65
```

32-bit PHP:

```
PHP_INT_MAX: 2147483647
C: 66, index: 176, strlen: 55, shift: 704, substr: mnopqrstuvw :: 176: 109
C: 117, index: 52, strlen: 55, shift: 109051904, substr: rstuvw :: 52: 114
C: 51, index: 608, strlen: 55, shift: 318767104, substr: UVWabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw :: 608: 85
C: 86, index: 855, strlen: 55, shift: -708837376, substr: hijklmnopqrstuvw :: 855: 104
```

Unfortunately, PHP doesn't support long integers on 32-bit systems at all natively (yet). The only way to work around this would be via an external package like [GMP](http://php.net/manual/book.gmp.php) or [BCMath](http://php.net/manual/book.bc.php). When PHP v7.0 is released later this year, this problem [should be fixed](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/size_t_and_int64_next).

Comment: I don't think BCMath supports Bitwise operations, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Amal: True, but it does support multiply, divide and power. Left and right shift are basically just multiplication by powers of 2.